# Overhead/downtime of partially indexing a column when no records meet the condition

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am needing to partially index a column when a single condition is met for a column (ex. some_column = 'some_value'). I am worried about the customer impact of triggering this new partial index and locking the table and am wondering how long that will take. In the databases where I am worried about the impact, there will be no records that meet the condition. Does this mean the overhead and time the table is locked would be drastically less than if there were records to index at the time of the index creation? The column in the where condition is indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not use the index on the column in the WHERE to speed up creation of the empty partial index.  It will still scan the full table, at however long it takes to do that.  Not needing to sort any tuples or generate any index leaf blocks will speed it up, but probably not 'drastically'.

If you are afraid it will hold the lock too long, you can create the index CONCURRENTLY.  This will take longer to do, but will hold a weaker lock while it does it.  It will still need a strong lock at the beginning and at the end, but it will only be held momentarily.